# How to pass parameter in swift controller to objective c model?

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I couldn't figure out on how to pass variables with type String in swift controller files and pass it to object written in objective-c. However, if I pass a string directly as a parameter it works just fine. Thank you for your help.

This is the objective-c class below

```
#import "Message.h"

@implementation Message

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.userID = dictionary[@"user_id"];
        self.username = dictionary[@"username"];
        self.avatarURL = dictionary[@"avatar_url"];
        self.text = dictionary[@"message"];
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithTestName:(NSString *)name withTestMessage:(NSString *)message withUserId:(NSString *)userId withAvatarUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.userID = userId;
        self.username = name;
        self.avatarURL = url;
        self.text = message;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

and this is the swift controller file

```
import UIKit

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

private var messages = [Message]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // I can pass the string successfully to the messages this way
    messages.append(Message(testName: "Test", withTestMessage: "Hello", withUserId: "1", withAvatarUrl: "http://www.example.com"))

    // After successfully making Api Request, I wasn't able to pass a variable as parameter
     if let data = dic as? [String:Any]{
                    let userId = data["user_id"] as? String
                    let url = data["avatar_url"] as? String
                    let name = data["name"] as? String
                    let message = data["message"] as? String

                    self.messages.append(Message(testName: name, withTestMessage: message, withUserId: userId, withAvatarUrl: url))

                }
     } 
}
```

Comment: You don't say why you were not able to pass your variables. Did you get an error at compile time? Or during execution? What was it? Etc. Edit your question to provide detail, say what you tried/didn't understand/etc. (don't try to add the details in a comment). Without such detail and indication of *effort* you will get downvoted/closed/ignored on SO. [As a hint, after a quick glance only, you might want to consider what the return *type* of `as?` is.

Comment: Your Objective C expects NSString while you init them as String ... So if let _: data["user_id"] as? String { let userId = data["user_id"] as! NSString // you cast it to the desired type for Message